# assignment of the return value of sizeof(int)

Tags: c

In an answer to this question [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

It was said that using `sizeof *sieve` in:

`int *sieve = malloc(length * sizeof *sieve);`

is better than using `sizeof(int)` as in:

`int *sieve = malloc(length * sizeof(int));`

as the later may cause errors, I don't know why it may cause errors ?

Comment: Cause error it seems to be in the other part.

Comment: might cause future errors if you only update one of the `int`s